# Selenium not updating website (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In a project I am doing, I am telling Selenium to go and scrape the data on the next page, which has the exact same URL.

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0x168296bb09e24a88805cb9c33356536b980d3fc5#balances")

iframe1 = driver.find_element_by_id('tokeholdersiframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
token_holders = soup.find_all('tr')

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
time.sleep(10)
token_holders2 = soup.find_all('tr') #I get the data from previous page (exact same as token_holder) rather than the new data.
```

However, Selenium doesn't update and I still get the same data from the previous page.

I tried using an implicit wait after the click:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried resetting the soup to the `driver.page_source`, as well as making the driver refind the `iframe` using `driver.find_element_by_id("id")`, but neither work.

Comment: please update the question with HTML code with iframe tag and what you wanna do after switching to iframe.

Comment: @cruisepandey I fixed my explanation a bit so it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

From the question I assume selenium is not waiting for the next page to load. One method of ensuring this happens (while not the most elegant) is to use known elements on the current page that you know will change and wait for that change to happen after clicking. You can use implicit wait see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html for details on how you can do this.

Alternatively, you can add an explicit wait after your click. ie

```
 from time import sleep
 ...

 driver.click(..);
 sleep(0.5) # Wait for half a second

 # Scrape the page
```

Comment: I tried that but it still fetched the information from the previous page. I updated my answer so you can see my code

Comment: Ok, I think I see what the issue is. You instantiate BeautifulSoup an instance of the first page so when you change pages, it is still working with the original copy. 

Try re-instantiating your soup after your timeout. [See this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50039613/9215583).

There is an anwsw

Comment: I am also currently having this issue, without Beautiful soup and just using driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath location') after a 10 second wait and viewing the change happen. If anyone still has solutions, please send!

Answer (score 0):

After you create a `soup` it won't dynamically update to reflect the `driver.page_source`. You need to create a new instance of `BeautifulSoup` and pass the updated page source.

```
token_holders = soup.find_all('tr')

driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
token_holders2 = soup.find_all('tr')
```

```
>>> token_holders[1:]
[<tr><td>1</td><td><span><a href="/token/0x168296bb09e24a88805cb9c33356536b980d3fc5?a=0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d" target="_parent">0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d</a></span></td><td>310847219.011683</td><td>31.0847%</td></tr>,
 <tr><td>2</td><td><span><a href="/token/0x168296bb09e24a88805cb9c33356536b980d3fc5?a=0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b" target="_parent">0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b</a></span></td><td>200000001</td><td>20.0000%</td></tr>,
...
]

>>> token_holders2[1:]
[<tr><td>51</td><td><span><a href="/token/0x168296bb09e24a88805cb9c33356536b980d3fc5?a=0x5473621d6d5f68561c4d3c6a8e23f705c8db7661" target="_parent">0x5473621d6d5f68561c4d3c6a8e23f705c8db7661</a></span></td><td>687442.69121294</td><td>0.0687%</td></tr>,
 <tr><td>52</td><td><span><a href="/token/0x168296bb09e24a88805cb9c33356536b980d3fc5?a=0xbc14ca2a57ea383a94281cc158f34870be345eb6" target="_parent">0xbc14ca2a57ea383a94281cc158f34870be345eb6</a></span></td><td>619772.39698</td><td>0.0620%</td></tr>,
 ...
]
```

Comment: I tried the code that you put in, and it gives me an error saying that there is an error with my "iframe1" variable with this message "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"tokeholdersiframe"}" Do you happen to know why it doesn't work? It works with the first page I scrape (also the id is "tokeholdersiframe"; I didn't misspell it

Comment: Never mind, I found the issue. I had to use time.sleep(5) after the token_holders2 = soup.find_all('tr') line